# How to poll a database using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Using a stored procedure, how do I poll a table every 15 minutes (maybe longer)? Based on what that polling finds, I'll be inserting data into another table.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the SQLAgent or some scheduler to run the procedure every 15 minutes.
A stored procedure is a transaction. You don't want one procedure just looping/waiting.

Is there a reason you don't want to use a trigger?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a job for a stored procedure in my opinion. This sounds more like something for SQL Agent.

That said, you could run a stored procedure that used a `WHILE` loop along with `WAITFOR` and that should do what you're trying to do.

```
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    -- Check your table, etc.

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:15:00.000'
END
```

An UPDATE/INSERT trigger could also be used for this, then you don't have to worry about anything constantly running and potentially failing.

Comment: In my opinion, using an infinite while loop with a delay in a stored procedure is a particularly bad idea....

Comment: I agree. The code is there for completeness, not because I actually suggest it :)

Comment: @Matthew Why is this such a bad idea? Is it just the unexpectedness or would this be resource intensive?

Comment: 1) If the Procedure goes into an infinite Loop, and is called from app/program, who would you be able to stop/monitor its execution? 2) you Cannot enforce only 1 instance of the Stored Procedure Running!? 3) SQL Agent has Error Logs/Notifications, etc which would greatly help you.

Comment: The Ideal solution would be to have a Stored Procedure which does your Task, and have it scheduled on a SQL Agent as suggested by Matthew.